# Regularity of a general hyperplane section

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $X\subset \mathbb{P}^n $ be a projective smooth variety of dimension $\geq 2$. It is easy to deduce that $\text{reg}(X\cap H)\leq \text{reg}(X)$ for a general hyperplane $H $, where reg stands for Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity.

I read in the literature that examples where the inequality is strict are known, but I've never seen one.

1. Is there a classic family of examples?
2. Is there a natural geometric condition to impose on $X$, or in the embedding, in order to obtain the strict inequality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you already looked at sections 4B.3/4 of Eisenbud's "The Geometry of Syzygies"? The inequality you want is an equality for what seems to be a very large class of varieties and hyperplane sections. For example, using Eisenbud's notation and numbering, if $S = k[x_0, \dots, x_n]$, $M$ is any finitely generated graded $S$ module, and $x \in S$ is a nzd on $M$, then reg($M$) = reg ($M/xM$); see Corollary 4.12. I'm guessing you want the CM regularity of the structure sheaf, but this agrees in a wide setting; see Proposition 4.16.

Comment: The inequality is always true, as you point out the equality happens when $X $ is for example ACM, even if $H$ is not general. I am interested in the strict inequality case.